# How to fetch client data using auth0?

Tags: javascript, authentication, auth0

I'v benn working on the website and tried to implement auth0 application using javascript. Unfortunately got the error(all personal links are removed form snippets):

```
Uncaught Error: Error: An error occurred when fetching client data for Lock: "link itself" timed out
    at index.js:528:7
```

Here is the function where the error appears:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    const lock = new Auth0Lock('client id', 'link, {
        autoclose: true,
        theme: {
            primaryColor: '#3498db',
            logo: 'https://cdn.auth0.com/styleguide/latest/lib/logos/img/badge.png',
        },
        languageDictionary: {
            title: 'Регистрация пользователя',
        },
    });

    const openRegistrationButton = document.getElementById('openRegistration');

    openRegistrationButton.addEventListener('click', function () {
        lock.show();
    });
});
```

I've already tried going through all the steps of implementation again but it didn't work out as well as trying to google for the error or solution. The auth0 provides the project with registration window but it returns an error in the console then the code is on the run and then i try to register a new user.

Comment: Can you fix the quote issue here: `const lock = new Auth0Lock('client id', 'link, {`. The `link` seems to be wrapped inside a quote but closing quote is missing.